# Using Identity Server 3 for Caching external authentication InMemory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, identityserver3

I'd like to use Identity Server 3 as caching authentication for an external identity provider. I'm trying to merge 2 examples of the provided samples from here> https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples

My goal would be to redirect the user from an MVC 5 application to an external address to make his/her login there (local login disabled). We can change the behavior of the MVC application listening there, so I can add the required Cookie/ HttpPost result changes for this to work. I'm stuck with .NET 4.6.2 tho. At successful login I would like to query the external source for Claims, and roles. So I'm copying parts of the `CustomUserService`, `MVC Authentication` samples.

When I have the first login of the user on the external site, I would store the `InMemoryUser` instance in the modified `UserServiceBase`, so second login within the memories lifetime doesn't have to go to the external resource. Rest would be handled with `Bearer` authentication, identity fed from the custom `UserServiceBase`. Whenever a `[Authorize(Roles = "SomeRole")]` is annotated, the external site is also queried for validation with a custom token specific for the external site (Web api call to it). I can't even get to that part, because the partial login and the redirect I cannot combine.

There are no meaningful `scope` requirements. The external site gives everything to build up the `Claims` for the user. While in development, there is no certificate, nor https requirement.

I guess it would be a `PartialLogin`. I can't make it work, so the given `externalregistration` endpoint doesn't give me 404, or infinite redirect, or missing partial login informations.

At the moment my code gives 404, tho as stated places [I have to `Map` it where my server is mapped to](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2479).

Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "http://localhost:20000/identity",

        ClientId = "aa",
        ClientSecret = "secret",
        Scope = "openid profile roles sampleApi",
        ResponseType = "id_token token",
        RedirectUri = "http://localhost:20000/",

        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "idsrv",
        UseTokenLifetime = false,

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
            {
                // I don't get there, so it doesn't really matter.
                var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
                    Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
                    Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                // get userinfo data
                var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
                    new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/userinfo"),
                    n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);

                var userInfo = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();
                userInfo.Claims.ToList().ForEach(ui => nid.AddClaim(new Claim(ui.Item1, ui.Item2)));

                // keep the id_token for logout
                nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                // add access token for sample API
                nid.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                // keep track of access token expiration
                nid.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(n.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToString()));

                // add some other app specific claim
                nid.AddClaim(new Claim("app_specific", "some data"));

                n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                    nid,
                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
            },

            RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
            {
                if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                {
                    var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                    if (idTokenHint != null)
                    {
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                    }
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });

    app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
    {
        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
            .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
            .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());

        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService, ExternalRegistrationUserService>();

        var options = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            RequireSsl = false,

            EnableWelcomePage = false,

            //SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),

            Factory = factory,

            AuthenticationOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions
            {
                EnableLocalLogin = false
            },

            LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions
            {
                EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true,
                WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = true,
                EnableHttpLogging = true,
                EnableKatanaLogging = true
            }
        };
        idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(options);

    });

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Clients.cs

```
public static class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientName = "MVC Client",
                ClientId = "aa",
                Flow = Flows.Implicit,
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:20000/"
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:20000/"
                },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    "openid",
                    "profile",
                    "roles",
                    "sampleApi"
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

ExternalRegistrationUserService.cs

```
using AuthenticateResult = IdentityServer3.Core.Models.AuthenticateResult;

public class ExternalRegistrationUserService : UserServiceBase
{
    private readonly OwinContext _ctx;

    public ExternalRegistrationUserService(OwinEnvironmentService owinEnv)
    {
        _ctx = new OwinContext(owinEnv.Environment);
    }

    public static List<InMemoryUser> Users = new List<InMemoryUser>();

    public override Task PreAuthenticateAsync(PreAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        var id = _ctx.Request.Query.Get("signin");
        // I get there, and the id is a generated code/token/whatever.
        context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult("/identity/externalregistration", id, "Alma",
            identityProvider: "idsrv", authenticationMethod: Constants.PartialSignInAuthenticationType);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public override Task AuthenticateExternalAsync(ExternalAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // I don't get there.
        var id = _ctx.Request.Query.Get("signin");
        context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult("/identity/externalregistration", id, "Alma",
            identityProvider: "idsrv", authenticationMethod: Constants.PartialSignInAuthenticationType);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public override Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        // issue the claims for the user
        var user = Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Subject == context.Subject.GetSubjectId());
        if (user != null)
        {
            context.IssuedClaims = user.Claims.Where(x => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(x.Type));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

}
```

AuthenticationController.cs

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    [Route("identity/externalregistration")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // I don't get there.
        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
        // If I don't route it below identity/externalregistration, than the variables below are empty.
        var authentication = ctx.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(Constants.PartialSignInAuthenticationType).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var dummy = ctx.Environment.GetIdentityServerPartialLoginAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var resumeUrl = ctx.Environment.GetPartialLoginResumeUrlAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        // external login page
        return Redirect("http://localhost:30000/Account/Login");
    }

    // there will be a Post version, where the 30000 port endpoint Redirects to.
    ...
}
```

[Logs](https://gist.github.com/mrtank/2c631dbdfbaa72f058cb2f9b30d0a2c6)

Comment: Can u move to identity sever 4

Comment: It would pull whole AspNetCore infrastructure as dependency

Comment: Without 4.6.2 restriction I have a working solution with OpenIddict

Comment: "pull whole AspNetCore infrastructure as dependency" - That is a problem why exactly?

Comment: Code runs in a picky environment, where dependencies should be minimum. We have to assure for nugets, and aspnetcore is not considered mature enough.